# SAS base programming referencing a SAS data set

Tags: sas

Which of the following programs correctly references a SAS data set named SalesAnalysis that is stored in a permanent SAS library?

```
A) 
data saleslibrary.salesanalysis;
set mydata.quarter1sales;
if sales>100000;
run;

B)
data mysales.totals;
set sales_99.salesanalysis;
if totalsales>50000;
run;

C)
proc print data=salesanalysis.quarter1;
var sales salesrep month;
run;

D)
proc freq data=1999data.salesanalysis; 
tables quarter*sales;
run;
```

My answer is  (a. data saleslibrary.salesanalysis)
but the solutions says Correct answer: (b. set mydata.quarter1sales),the explaination goes : "Librefs must be 1 to 8 characters long, must begin with a letter or underscore, and can contain only letters, numbers, or underscores. After you assign a libref, you specify it as the first element in the two-level name for a SAS file."

However the question asks for SalesAnalysis, so is the solution wrong?  I am wondering if "saleslibrary.salesanalysis" is the original library + file name and "mydata.quarter1sales" is the library name +file name for output data?

Comment: Format your code in the future

Comment: Why are you editing your question to delete it? If you do so, there's no reason to answer any of your future questions. Although we answer questions to help you the goal is also to create a reference for future users. Deleting or editing questions after the fact is inconsiderate.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is B.

- A -> the libname reference is too long, it can only be 8 characters.
- B -> Does refer to the data set in question.
- C -> Again, not
  referring to salesAnalysis as a data set but a library
- D -> Library
  name is incorrect, it cannot start with a number.

The format to reference a SAS data set is

```
 LIBNAME.dataSetName;
```

Where libname follows the rules in the question and data set name rules are also correctly applied.

Answer (score 0):

Key word is "referencing"...not "creating". Assuming your studying for the BASE 9 exam...and you have a bootleg study guide.

Referencing the original formatted data provided before the edit, the answer is in fact `b.`, because the real answer `b.` reads `set sales_99.salesanalysis;`, its just marked as "f." in the study guide you are using. This makes sense because you can assume your answers (a.-n. as presented) can be broken down into 4 very obvious data steps.

the key word `data` will create a data set, the key word `set` will reference one

Comment: That is awesome ! Thank you SMW. You  absolutely cleared my doubts !

Comment: NP. Please accept as an answer if its what you needed.

Comment: I would disagree with this answer, as long as the libname and dataset name was correct, even though it creates a dataset the first one would also be correct. It's incorrect because the libname is not valid.